# How can I user JS variable in a Razor TAG or any idea what can I do

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I create an Excel File in the controller as a `TempData` server-side. But when I was testing it via localhost this line of code works `window.location = '/Reports/Download?fileGuid=' + data.FileGuid + '&filename=' + data.FileName;`

But just when I mounted it on the server and I execute this same code via ajax this is the result: `404 - File or directory not found`.

If I use a `@URL.Action` it will work but the `data.fileGuid` and `data.fileName` is in data that I receive via the ajax call and those are JavaScript variables so I can't put them in a Razor TAG.

1. This is the code I have.

   ```
      $.ajax({
           url: @Url.Action("ReportExcelData", "Reports"),
           data: { 'json': JSON.stringify(jsonObjSearch) },
           type: "POST",
           cache: false,

           success: function (data) {

               window.location = '/Reports/Download?fileGuid=' + data.FileGuid
                   + '&filename=' + data.FileName;
           },
           error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
           }
       })
   ```

Any suggestions, or i can use something like this                     `window.location = "@Url.Action("/Reports/Download?fileGuid=" + data.FileGuid + "&filename=" + data.FileName, "Reports")"`.

Sorry for the fact that English is not my first language.

Comment: `var url = '@Url.Action( "Download", "Reports")'?FileGuid=" + data.FileGuid + "&filename=" + data.FileName;` (assuming your script is not in an external `.js` file

Comment: Thanks it works, but I had to change a little bit the code, `var url = '@Url.Action("Download", "Reports")'+"?FileGuid=" + data.FileGuid + "&filename=" + data.FileName;`